# Python or PowerShell with Azure FileShare

Tags: python, azure, azure-storage, azure-files

I wanted to execute one `exe`, once any specific file comes to a Azure fileshare using python or powershell.

How could we do it, I mean I don't want to use azure webjob.

Is it possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Following PSH command can be used to get a file instance, if the file not exist, it will report 404 error.

```
Get-AzureStorageFile -ShareName $shareName -Path $testfile
```

To execute an exe in Powershell, there are several ways, see https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx